# Unable to add FileInfo.Name items from string[] to a List<string> field

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list, nullreferenceexception

I have the following method, which is meant to add file names to a `List<string>` so that the desired order of the files is stored in the `Program` class:

```
    private static void ConvertPdfs()
    {
        // Get the word files FileInfo
        FileInfo[] wordFileInfo = DataGrabber.GetHrWordFileInfo(sourceFolder, spSite, policyListName, sortBy);

        foreach (FileInfo file in wordFileInfo)
        {
            // Create the ordered list - this adds each document to the list in the correct oder (sort in CAML query)
            orderedListOfFileNames.Add(file.Name);                
        }           
        Converter convert = new Converter();
        convert.ToPdf(wordFileInfo, targetPdf);
    }
```

Where `ordereListOfFileNames` is a field in that same class:

```
 private static List<string> orderedListOfFileNames; // Stil static ...
```

When the method loops around wordFileInfo, I am seeing this exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' Occurred in PdfConverter.exe
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

However, I can see that `wordFileInfo` contains 22 items, all of which have a name.

Is the issue here the fact that `orderedListOfFileNames` has not been initialised properly?

Comment: [What is a `NullReferenceException` and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/447156)

Comment: How many elements does wordFileInfo have? Maybe an element of wordFileInfo is null?

Comment: Can you show the code of "ToPdf" function? I think that the error is on PDFConverter input parameter

Comment: After properly instantiating the `orderedListOfFileNames` field, the error disappeared (see un-lucky's answer).

Comment: How could "orderedListOfFileNames" contain 22 items without been initialized? Was it initialized at some other point?

Comment: LOL, now it is clear as the Invisible Man.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to instantiate the  `orderedListOfFileNames` before adding value to the list using a new operotor as like the following:

```
private static List<string> orderedListOfFileNames= new List<string>();
```

Answer (score 2):

instantiate  is not necessary when you are doing the following so thats not the issue.

```
FileInfo[] wordFileInfo = DataGrabber.GetHrWordFileInfo(sourceFolder, spSite, policyListName, sortBy);
```

But still when you do the above code wordFileInfo becomes null, so `DataGrabber.GetHrWordFileInfo(sourceFolder, spSite, policyListName, sortB)` something happends here.